# Deffered и delay

Tags: jquery

Всем добрый день, пытаюсь реализовать такую часть кода, нужно чтобы GJ выводилось после задержки в 3500, но почему то не работает, подскажите, где ошибка пожалуйста

```html
var b=$.Deferred();
  var status;
  var form_data=$('#contact_form').serialize();
  
  $('button').append('<div class="load_form">').delay(3500,b.resolve);
  var post_form=$.ajax ({ 
    type:"POST",
    url: "send.php",
    async: false,
    data: form_data,
    success: function (msg){
     status=parseInt(msg);
    }
   });
  
  $.when (b,post_form).done(function(){alert('GJ');});
```